# C# SQLiteDataAdapter Fill Method is slow

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, observablecollection

the problem domain is that I have an db file with like ~90000 rows and 6 columns. I got an Select query where I get all the rows and columns that are necessary for me and that works fine. Now is the thing that I fill a DataTable with those records. I do this with SQliteDataAdapter Fill Method and this takes about ~1,3 seconds and after this I fill my ObservableCollection (<--Bound to DataGrid) with this data and this takes also about ~1,3 seconds. So here is my code

```
private void GetSelectedMaterial()
    {
        DataTable dtMaterial = new DataTable();
        materialColl.Clear(); // Clearing ObservableCollection

        Trace.WriteLine("GetSelectedMaterial TS " + DateTime.Now + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(dbConnection))
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            connection.Open();

            query = "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Materialliste LEFT JOIN(SELECT * FROM Tbl_Besitzt k WHERE k.TechnikID = '" + teTechnikID + "') as k ON k.MaterialID = Tbl_Materialliste.MaterialID";

            dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, connection);
            Trace.WriteLine("query: " + DateTime.Now + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

            dtMaterial.Columns.Add("Checked", typeof(bool));
            Trace.WriteLine("here comes the fill: " + DateTime.Now + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            dataAdapter.Fill(dtMaterial);

            Trace.WriteLine("Checkbox: " + DateTime.Now + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
            DetermineCheckBox(dtMaterial, teTechnikID, 8);
            Trace.WriteLine("SQL TS: " + DateTime.Now + DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        }

        FillMaterialColl(dtMaterial);
    }

    private void FillMaterialColl(DataTable dtMaterial)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in dtMaterial.Rows)
        {
            Material mat = new Material();

            mat.isChecked = (bool)dr.ItemArray[0];
            mat.materialID = (string)dr.ItemArray[1];
            mat.materialkurztext = (string)dr.ItemArray[2];
            mat.herstellername = (string)dr.ItemArray[3];
            mat.herArtikenummer = (string)dr.ItemArray[4];
            mat.dokument = (string)dr.ItemArray[5];
            mat.substMaterial = (string)dr.ItemArray[6];

            materialColl.Add(mat);
        }
    }
```

I know ObservableCollections are draining performance but is there some way to do this in another way? Some say to use DataReader instead of DataAdapter but DataAdapter shall use DataReader so I think there is no improvement in performance. So the main problem is that that process takes to long and user experience is not so good if showing new material takes about 3-4 seconds..

**EDIT**
So here comes my DB design:
[image]

It is a many-to-many relationship between Tbl_Material and Tbl_Technik
And my Select query gives me ALL entrys from Tbl_Material (~90k) and in addition those columns from Tbl_Besitzt where I can find the technikID
So that I can filter (for an checkbox) which entrys belong to my MaterialID
In my DB file MaterialId from Tbl_Materialliste is a PK and also TechnikID from Tbl_Technik - not that you are wondering in the design image, I didnt get they into the model..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes thats right, but it doesnt change if I do this without backgroud thread... I will edit my code so that the thread isnt necessary... any other helping ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to investigate the performance issues of a database without knowing its schema and design. In your SQL query, there is a `join` expression. You need to ensure that the corresponding data fields are indexed in order to make the join operation fast. This depends also on the data size of **both** tables.

To speed up the displaying of the search results, you should avoid adding them item-by-item in your `ObservableCollection<T>`. This is because each time you add a new item, the Binding Engine transfers this item to the `DataGrid` causing the grid to perform all the actions it needs to display a record.

If you don't really need the collection to be observable (e.g. you won't add or remove any items in the view), then just make it to an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<Material> Materials
{
    get { return this.materials; }
    private set
    {
         // Using the PRISM-like implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged here
         // Change this to yours
         this.SetProperty(ref this.materials, value);
    }
}
```

In you method, create a local `List<Material>`, fill it, and then expose to the view:

```
List<Material> materials = new List<Material>();
// fill the list here
// ...
// finally, assign the result to your property causing the binding to do the job once
this.Materials = materials;
```

If you need the `ObservableCollection<T>` though, you can do the same trick - create a local copy, fill it, and finally expose.

If this doesn't help, you should try using the UI virtualization. This is a rather big topic, but there is a lot of information on the net.

Comment: I changed it the way you described and now it's like ~250ms for the filling of the list! Thanks a lot! I will edit my post so you can see my db design so maybe you can take a look?